# Maintain standalone composer package

Tags: php, version-control, frameworks, package, composer-php

I'm developing an application that consists of several modules/packages which i also want to offer as standalone packages. I know how to create composer packages but i'm not exactly sure on the best way to do the actual development and need your help on this.

One way would be installing the packages with composer but that would mean that, for each change, i would have to commit and then do a `composer update` on my app, just to able to test it. Not very practical.

Another way would be to have them included in my app, although having the package internal structure. That would work fine for developing but would pose a problem on publishing individual packages since all the code would belong to the same repository.

I think a good example on this is the way modern frameworks, like Laravel, are available. They have the whole code available in a repository but, at the same time, have each individual component available standalone.

What's the best way (in your opinion) to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 uses Git subtree split.  That is, a single development repository which is split into multiple repositories later.

Don't make any mistake about it though, the code is the same, but they "are different" repositories, and the procedure to maintaining them is rather long winded.

http://www.craftitonline.com/2012/03/git-subtree-split-this-is-what-symfony2-does-every-night-to-set-standalone-components/